# What type of flask should I use to culture NTERA2 embryonic cancer stem cells?

Tags: molecular-biology, cancer, cell-culture, stem-cells

I'm just starting my MSc research and I am in the process of making a list of equipments/consumables to order. Is there a specific flask in which I can culture NTERA2 (NTERA2/D1) cell line?

Comment: I just use regular TC-treated Petri dishes and flasks - nothing special.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a [protocol](http://www.uwencode.org/media/protocols/cell_culture/human/NT2-D1_protocol.pdf) by ATCC for NTERM2 cells, and it didn't mention any specific flask, so any cell culture flask would do. Since ATCC is basically a cell culture bank I trust that their protocol is valid.